# Why everytime open a new flutter project this error appear?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have tried a different kind of ways to resolve the error but still can't resolve, and I'm still a new learner on flutter. But I still can run the whole project well without resolving the error shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no error that's just ide warning I think, that could be about typo etc, If you click to lamp and show us the suggestions then we can help more.
But I tried this part of code and get different warning and solved it with add @ to override such as;

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(){
    @override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine){
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

If that's show same you need to check your ide settings, probably there is a missing plugin(Dart or Flutter).

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for answering me question, and I click on the lamp it's suggesting me to create annotation 'NonNull'. I also found warning in build.gradle where it call me to create class GradleException.

Comment: Your plugins look fine, if it says create annotion NonNull, I get two idea about it, firstly can you try to import "android.support.annotation.NonNull" instead of "androidx.annotion.NoNull". Secondly you maybe use intellij idea so check this link it could be related: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html